# Как заставить работать скрипт после перезагрузки представления через ajax? (drupal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

Есть представление, в котором открыт фильтр по заголовку, после ввода слова, представление перезагружается через ajax, и перестает работать мой самописный аккордеон, знаю что есть готовый модуль. Но мне принципиально именно научиться вешать скрипты и после срабатывания ajax.

На скрине представление:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это мой скрипт, который сворачивает/разворачивает элемент при клике по заголовку

```js
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.a_module = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.view-id-question_answer.view-display-id-page .views-field-title').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.views-row').siblings().removeClass('active').find('.views-field-body').slideUp(200);
        if ($(this).parents('.views-row').hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).parents('.views-row').removeClass('active').find('.views-field-body').slideUp(200);
        } else {
          $(this).parents('.views-row').addClass('active').find('.views-field-body').slideDown(200);
        }
      })
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

сейчас после перезагрузки через ajax при клике функция срабатывает 2 раза (разворачивает и сворачивает элемент)

думаю это связано с тем что `attach: function (context, settings)` запускает все внутри себя как бы два раза ну например при отправке запроса на сервер и при получении, если это так и я не бред написал, то подскажите, как сделать, чтобы функция работала как надо (один клик разворачивает, следующий клик сворачивает), а не многократно

Comment: Обычно такие вещи решаются через .toggle(); раз используете jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В некоторых ситуациях `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` может вызываться несколько раз, соответственно `Drupal.behaviors.a_module.attach()` повешает на целевой элемент несколько click обработчиков. Для того, чтобы бихэвиор отрабатывал только 1 раз, можно проверять, есть ли у целевого элемента уникальный CSS класс. Если класса у целевого элемента нет, то добавить этому элементу уникальный класс и выполнить код бихэвиора, в противном случае проигнорировать обработку.

```
    ...
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var cls = 'a_module_processed'
        , $target = $('.view-id-question_answer.view-display-id-page .views-field-title', context);
      if ($target.hasClass(cls)) {
        return;
      }
      $target.addClass(cls).click(function() {
   ...
```